# Magento change quote/cart total after add product to cart

Tags: magento, cart, quote

I have a scenario that when the customer adds products to the cart I will free 1 qty of minimum item (almost like salesrule "buy x get y"). So, I need to change the quote total after the products have been added to the cart.

I tried several events: `checkout_cart_product_add_after`, `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`, `sales_quote_collect_totals_after`... and when I change the quotes total and log right that time, the total has changed, but when I go to shopping cart page, it is unchanged.

I tried getting the quote by: `$observer->getEvent()->getQuote()`, or `$session->getQuote()` and also collected quote total again, but nothing happened.

Is there any way to change the quote/cart's total right after adding products to the cart (or cartView action)???